# How to connect to Orange Internet Everywhere with a Huawei E160 Modem on Mac OS X Lion (10.7)

Tags: macos, osx-lion, internet-connection

I tried it for Orange Romania and the original connect software and drivers that come with the modem do not work, nor do those on the original Orange Romania website. The software actually made my computer unresponsive at one point and kept acting out all the time, while still not providing access to the internet (No device connected).

Answer (score 1):

It is an issue with the new Lion kernel, which is all 64bit, and the crappy software Orange makes.

I did not manage to make it work with the Orange Internet Everywhere software, but I did follow this guy's tip http://www.sociallyinert.com/?p=9 and made it work through a new network interface in System Preferences, which turns out is a better way of connecting anyway. Works for Orange Romania and for Orange UK for sure. Feel free to add any other countries that  also fit in.

In order to make it work you have to:

1. Download the [Huawei Universal 10.7 Mac Package Driver Download](http://www.sociallyinert.com/downloads/huawei_universal_425_05.pkg.zip) and install it;
2. Go to System Preferences > Network and click the "+" sign and from the popup choose your Huawei Modem and give it a name like "Orange".
3. In the new network interface you created put this connect information:

Telephone number: *99#
Account name: orange
Password: orange

And click "Connect". It may ask you to save the preferences. Choose Yes.

DONE. It should now have connected to the internet. Now anytime you connect your Huawei modem you only need to go to System Preferences > Network > Orange and click Connect.

Hope this helps.

ps. You can also put an icon in your menu bar and connect from there. For this while in System Preferences > Network > Orange - click "Show modem status in menu bar". It's now in your menu bar - it looks like a telephone - and you can connect faster.

Comment: One has to deactivate the PIN request first. Apple Network can't ask for the PIN. So deactivate it first. I did it with my old computer (10.6.) where I still had the software "Mobile Partner". Once the PIN request is deactivated it will work as written above with 10.7.x

Comment: I am the only one that does not like to download drivers from random sites on the internet?